# Preauth and split payment in paypal using REST APIs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, ruby-on-rails-5, paypal-adaptive-payments

1. I have buyer and seller in my platform.

   2. When the buyer purchases a product, at the same time the amount should be captured from his account, and on product delivery the seller should receive the amount and admin gets 10% as platform charge.
   3. This implementation is very easy in **stripe** but I want this to implemented in **Russia, France, and Germany** and stripe is not supporting these countries.
   4. So, I want to go with **PayPal**.
   5. I am googled and found that **adaptive payment** is used for that.
   6. But on the paypal documentation page, it is written that **adaptive payment is restricted**. Paypal's documentation is very confusing and limited.

**I want some can help me on that or can share some links for my better understanding.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a "quick and easy" solution available right now.

They have added the [Marketplaces API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/) which will replace what Adaptive Payments was doing, but it's not ready for public use yet.

You might be interested in this article about [PayPal split payments with Express Checkout](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-split-payments-express-checkout-billing-agreements-reference-transactions/).  It outlines a few alternative methods to get this done.

Comment: Does express checkout support preauth, capture, refund, etc?

Comment: Yes, it supports all of that.